# ASPxListBox items to string

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, devexpress, tostring

This should be easy, but I'm failing to do this. I have ASPxListBox with checkbox option turned on. So I'd like to have selected items in one string. Like this:

> item1,item4,item9

and so on.

Notice that they should be divided by "," and last comma deleted.

Tried something like this, but won't work:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < lb1.Items.Count; i++)
    sb.Append(lb1.Items[i].Selected ? lb1.Items[i].Text + "," : "");
TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

(I asked similar question before, but as I havent mention that this is ASPxListBox, suggestions I got wont works.

So, this is Visual Studio 2008, Devexpress 9.3 and .NET framework 3.5

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@keyboardP: your solution is rather ok on my mind, so +1.

Moreover, you can find a similar solution in the DevExpress code central:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/e/E2625.aspx

```
ASPxListBox listBox = instance;

string selectedItemsAsString = string.Empty;

foreach (ListEditItem item in listBox.SelectedItems)
    selectedItemsAsString += item.Value + ";";

if (selectedItemsAsString.Length > 0)
    selectedItemsAsString = selectedItemsAsString.Trim(new char[] { ';' });
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with `ASPxListBox`, but couldn't you just loop through and then remove the last comma by getting the substring?

```
 string csvList = sb.ToString();
 TextBox1.Text = csvList.Substring(0, csvList.LastIndexOf(','));
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with aspxlistbox but You can write something like this-

```
    String Finaloutput="";
    for (int i = 0; i < lb1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
       string output= lb1.Items[i].Selected ? lb1.Items[i].Text + "," : "";
       Finaloutput += output;
    }
    TextBox1.Text = Finaloutput.TrimEnd(',');
```